# Content-ID, HTML, multipart и Thunderbird

Tags: email, mime

Все картинки в TB включены, HTML показывает. Фрагмент письма:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="=-ame9Z0FPhFlUumuyMSIsirqzWNNga"
...

--=-ame9Z0FPhFlUumuyMSIsirqzWNNga
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii

<html><head><title>title</title></head><body>
<img src="cid:file@1" />
</body></html>

--=-ame9Z0FPhFlUumuyMSIsirqzWNNga
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: image/png; name="test.png"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.png"
Content-ID: <file@1>

...
```

Всякие веб-мейлы показывают как и задумано (gmail, мейлру, яндекс, squirrelmail на своём домене etc). Даже древний Outlook-XP показывает. TB - нет. Ему какие-то отдельные настройки нужны, или я где-то проглючил с Content-ID или чем-то ещё?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если совсем по-хорошему, то картинка должна идти не аттачментом, а с `Content-Disposition: inline`, а `Content-Type` всего письма (или HTML части с картинкой) должен быть `multipart/related`.

Comment: По-хорошему это какой RFC? Все, прочитанные мной, говорят, что и `attachment` сгодится. Пробовал `inline` - ничего не меняется (показывают все, кроме TB). А ссылки с `Content-ID` должны корректно работать в любом случае, если все находится внутри одного контейнера.

Comment: Content-type "всего письма" может быть разным, но картинки и текстовая часть в любом случае сидят в одном контейнере типа `"multipart/mixed"`

Comment: Yep! Спасибо, прозрел.

Comment: @klopp: rfc2387, про разницу между `mixed`,`related` и `alternative` уже не надо рассказывать,я так понимаю? :)

Comment: Ага. Закопался в работу с alternative, а контейнер более высокого уровня был mixed, вот и лень было думать, пока всё это в каких-то мейлерах выглядело нормально. Ну, как грится, ждите на гитхабе. Вот только ещё с текучестью памяти при TLS-сессиях разобраться бы...